# Changing javax.xml.bind to jakarta.xml.bind getting missing an @XmlRootElement annotation issue

Tags: java, jaxb, jakarta-migration

After changing javax.xml.bind to jakarta.xml.bind getting missing an @XmlRootElement annotation issue. Annotation  **@XmlRootElement** is already present in the Car class. can you please help me on this.

```css
jakarta.xml.bind.MarshalException with linked exception: [com.sun.istack.SAXException2: unable to marshal type "com.test.v2.Car" as an element because it is missing an @XmlRootElement annotation]
```

Using code for Marshalling:

```js
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Car.class);
        Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
        jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        jaxbMarshaller.marshal(car, byteArrayOutputStream);
        byteArrayOutputStream.close();
        String payloadString = String.valueOf(byteArrayOutputStream);
```

```js
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(
    name = "",
    propOrder = {
        "a",
        "b",
        "c"
    }
)
@XmlRootElement(
    name = "Car"
)
public class Car {
    String a;

    String b;

    String c;
    public String getA() {
        return this.A;
    }

    public String getB() {
        return this.B;
    }
    public String getC() {
        return this.C;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd like to help you solve your problem but could you precise your change from `javax.xml.bind` to `jakarta.xml.bind` ? You mean you changed your dependencies from `javax` to `jakarta` for jaxb ? What import is used in your `Car` class for `@XmlRootElement` ? Thanks

Comment: I have the same issue and we are using jakarta now everywhere _(I checked 
everywhere I could imagine it might be relevant)_

Comment: @rala or @ritu : could you share some information like `pom.xml` or java source file to check dependencies / imports are correct ?